# How to update 50 million+ rows in single table as fast?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, query-optimization

I am trying to update more then 50m rows based on SELECT of another table, but this process is taking more then 15 hours, what can I do more to downsize the time window to complete the update.
SQL query:

```
start transaction;
UPDATE holdings_all a
INNER JOIN asset b ON a.asset = b.name
SET a.AssetID = b.asset_id;
commit;
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `holdings_all` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateAdded` date NOT NULL,
  `Fund` char(96) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Asset` char(96) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssetID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weighting` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ticker` char(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Style` char(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstBought` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `SharesOwned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sector` char(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(13,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` char(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Currency` char(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PriceUSD` decimal(13,6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DateAddedFundTickerWeighting_UNIQUE` (`DateAdded`,`Fund`,`Ticker`,`Weighting`),
  KEY `Fund` (`Fund`),
  KEY `DateAdded` (`DateAdded`),
  KEY `FundTicker` (`Fund`,`Ticker`),
  KEY `Asset` (`Asset`),
  KEY `DateAdded_Fund` (`DateAdded`,`Fund`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `asset_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asset_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
port=3366
innodb-page-size=65536
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
[client]
port=3366
```

Machine specs:

```
RAM: 16 GB
CPU: 06 cores
DISK: M.2 1TB
```

Comment: Is this a production database where are other things reading holdings_all?

Comment: @Schwern No, this is just in local dev machine.

Comment: what does `explain update holdings_all a
INNER JOIN asset b ON a.asset = b.name
SET a.AssetID = b.asset_id` show?

Comment: I don't understand the schema.  The columns read like the definition of one fund.  Do you really have 50M different funds??  I don't think there are that many in the world.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, there are more then 50M, and that because I save their rates weekly, so basically they are duplicated.

Comment: @HAßdøµ - Is `DateAdded` really the date of the `Price` and a couple of other columns?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a number of things to try, in no particular order.

You have many indexes in the table, and some are probably redundant.

- `Fund` is redundant given `(Fund, Ticker)`
- `DateAdded` and `(DateAdded, Fund)` are both redundant given `(DateAdded, Fund, Ticker, Weighting)`

Perhaps some other indexes are not needed. It depends on the queries you need to run.

Edit: This might not be so important in your case, since InnoDB does not need to update indexes on other columns if you haven't changed them with your UPDATE statement. But they would need to be written if you INSERT or DELETE. Thanks to the comment from @ysth for this reminder.

The columns you're joining on, `holdings_all.Asset` and `asset.name` use different character sets. The join might use an index. I recommend to update all your tables to the same character set and collation, and standardize on utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE holdings_all CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
ALTER TABLE asset CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

I estimate your table takes about 57GB to store. But you only have a buffer pool of 4GB, and this must be shared with any other tables you have. This means your UPDATE of the whole table will have to evict pages and load other pages over and over. It's probably highly dependent on the speed of your hard drive.

You should upgrade the server so it has an SSD or NVMe hard drive, and enough RAM that you can configure the buffer pool at least 10x its current size.

I understand this would require a more expensive server, but if you are working with large-scale data, you should use the right hardware for that job, or else accept that it will take a long time.

Comment: re "every row you update has to update every index in the table"  this is true for postgres, it is not true for innodb

Comment: @ysth Are you referring to the change buffer? It's true this defers changes to non-unique indexes, but they still have to do that write eventually.

Comment: no.  if you update only non-indexed fields, no indexes besides the primary key need any writes at all.

Comment: Okay yes, good point. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If "updating" means "replacing the entire table", then do it a much faster way:

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE holdings_all;`
2. Load `new` with the new data.
3. `RENAME TABLE holdings_all TO old, new TO holdings_all;`
4. `DROP TABLE old;`

Other tips and techniques for big deletes and updates:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

If it is actually non-static data, then at least split it into two tables -- the static info (ticker, style, currency, etc) and the data to be updated (date, price, sharedowned, etc).

Also, use `VARCHAR`, not `CHAR`.

Comment: No, I am just updating some columns. From my knowledge using `VARCHAR` will decrease speed because in every time a data inserted or changed, its length must be calculated, correct where I am wrong here.

Comment: `CHAR` vs `VARCHAR` is insignificant in InnoDB.  A copy of the _row_ will be made in case of `ROLLBACK` or crash.  With MyISAM, `CHAR` had a benefit in limited situations.  But even for that Engine, the benefit was overrated.

Comment: @HAßdøµ - Also.. When using only 10 columns out of a declaration of 96 -- that's 86 extra bytes on disk.  The I/O overhead and the handling of bulky rows far outweigh the perceived benefit.  Use `CHAR` _only_ for truly fixed-length columns.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Split that table into two tables.

- The constant stuff (ticker, fund, date_bought, etc)
- The stuff that changes weekly (price, date, etc)

Be sure to pick a suitable `PRIMARY KEY` (such as `ticker`) for the first table.  The second table would also have a `ticker` column so that they can be `JOINed` together.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is probably `PRIMARY KEY(ticker, date)`

The sloooow `UPDATE` would then become

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ticker, date, price, ...)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         price = VALUES(price),   -- whatever you might need to update
         ...
```

Or, since the data seems to be coming from another table,:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ticker, date, price, ...)
    SELECT ticker, date, price, ...
        FROM that_other_table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         price = VALUES(price),   -- whatever you might need to update
         ...
```